# Subsetting a dataframe based on two attributes of a second df (R)

Tags: r, subset, topology

I have two dataframes (`elementdf` and `nodedf`) and I want to subset the second (`elementdf`) if `nid` between the dataframes match AND the z field of `nodedf` is >= 90.

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9)
v2 <- c(90, 90, 90, 40, 20, 20, 80, 80)
nodedf <- data.frame(v1, v2)
names(nodedf)  <- c("nid", "z") 

v3 <- c(1, 2)
v4 <- c(1, 5)
v5 <- c(2, 6)
v6 <- c(3, 7)
v7 <- c(4, 9)

elementdf <- data.frame(v3, v4, v5, v6, v7)
names(elementdf)  <- c("eid", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4")
```

I don't need every `nid` in `elementdf` to be `TRUE`: just as long as one is, then it qualifies for the subset (as long as its `nid` is also >= 90).

Desired output is:

```
eid n1 n2 n3 n4
1   1  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: So what's the desired output here?

Comment: Added in the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Having data in wide format makes this harder. Here we use `tidyr` to do some reshaping to make the join possible.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
elementdf %>% 
  gather(source, nid, -eid) %>% 
  inner_join(nodedf %>% filter(z>=90)) %>% 
  semi_join(elementdf, .)
```